# Plotly R hovertext over line / shapes

Tags: r, plotly

Is it possible to add hover information to a line/shapes object?

The below code generates a plot with hoverinformation over the 2 points.

```
library(plotly)

line <- list(type = "line", line = list(color = "black"), xref = "x", 
             yref = "y", x0 = 0, x1 = 1, y0 = 1, y1 = 1)

plot_ly(data.frame(i = 0:1, j = 1:2), x = ~i, y =~j, hoverinfo = "text", 
        text = ~c("p1", "p2")) %>% 
add_markers() %>% 
plotly::layout(shapes = line)
```

Is it somehow possible to add something like

```
%>% plotly::layout(shapes = line, text = "l1")
```

to get hover information over the line? (Obviously this code does not work.)

Comment: As far as I know hovertext can only be shown for traces. You could add an invisible helper trace which has the same coordinates as the shapes to get the hover effect.